SQL rollup to add a total row for multiple columns
I am using the employee data set from Kaggle - Dataset
I created a pivot table on top of this for EmployeeClassificationType and EmployeeStatus
with pivotTable as 
(
    select 
        EmployeeClassificationType, [Active], [Future Start], 
        [Leave of Absence], [Terminated for Cause], 
        [Voluntarily Terminated],
        ([Active] + [Future Start] + [Leave of Absence] + [Terminated for Cause] + [Voluntarily Terminated]) as total
    from 
        (select 
             EmployeeStatus, EmployeeClassificationType, count(*) as total
         from  
             employee_data
         group by 
             EmployeeStatus, EmployeeClassificationType) a
    pivot
        (sum(total)
            for employeeStatus in ([Active], [Future Start], [Leave of Absence], [Terminated for Cause], [Voluntarily Terminated])
        ) as pivotTable
)
-- rollup and find the grand total as well as add a row to total 
select * 
from pivotTable

The output looks like this:

I want to add a row for totals as shown in this screenshot:

I have tried using rollup with all columns but its seems to not work
select 
    coalesce(EmployeeClassificationType, 'Grand Total') as EmployeeClassificationType,
    sum(Active) as Active,
    sum([Future Start]) as [Future Start],
    sum([Leave of Absence]) as [Leave of Absence],
    sum([Terminated for Cause]) as [Terminated for Cause],
    sum([Voluntarily Terminated]) as [Voluntarily Terminated],
    sum(total) as 'Grand Total'
from 
    pivotTable
group by 
    rollup(EmployeeClassificationType, Active, [Future Start], [Leave of Absence], [Terminated for Cause]), [Voluntarily Terminated]

or
select 
    *,
    sum(total) as 'Grand Total'
from 
    pivotTable
group by 
    rollup(EmployeeClassificationType, Active, [Future Start], [Leave of Absence], [Terminated for Cause]), [Voluntarily Terminated], total



As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

And please ensure your question is self contained with a [mre] i.e. doesn't require people to visit off-site links in order to understand your question.

You could put the results in a temp table and union the detail and total from the same but this seems wrong. What is consuming the data? Normally the rollup would be added in that. For instance, if you were using PowerBi, it would do the rollup not SQL.

@strattonn I am not using any Reporting tool such as PowerBI, I wanted to know how to do this using only SQL, since it is possible to find the total with 1 or 2 columns in the rollup but using the whole set does not yield the expected output.

@Vinita If you change your rollup line to rollup(EmployeeClassificationType) does it work?

Seems like a problem for the reporting layer. If you want to do this in SQL then only the grouping keys belong in rollup().

For the sake of your sanity, avoid creating column names with spaces in them.

data
CREATE TABLE pivotTable (
   EmployeeClassificationType VARCHAR(90)  
  ,Active                     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,FutureStart                INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LeaveOfAbsence             INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,TerminatedForCause         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,VoluntarilyTerminated      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,total                      INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO pivotTable 
(EmployeeClassificationType,Active,FutureStart,LeaveOfAbsence,TerminatedForCause,VoluntarilyTerminated,total) VALUES 
('Full-Time',840,26,21,24,102,1013),
('Part-Time',779,20,35,15,105,954),
('Temporary',839,23,30,27,114,1033);

query use group by .... with rollup  not group by rollup(...)and ISNULL to cover null values for EmployeeClassificationType column
SELECT
ISNULL(EmployeeClassificationType,'TOTAL'),
SUM(Active) Active,
SUM(FutureStart)  FutureStart,
SUM(LeaveOfAbsence)   LeaveOfAbsence,
SUM(TerminatedForCause)  TerminatedForCause,
SUM(VoluntarilyTerminated)  VoluntarilyTerminated,
SUM(total) total
FROM 
pivotTable
 group 
    by EmployeeClassificationType with rollup;

add above query to your with CTE
with pivotTable as 
(
    select 
        EmployeeClassificationType, [Active], [Future Start], 
        [Leave of Absence], [Terminated for Cause], 
        [Voluntarily Terminated],
        ([Active] + [Future Start] + [Leave of Absence] + [Terminated for Cause] + [Voluntarily Terminated]) as total
    from 
        (select 
             EmployeeStatus, EmployeeClassificationType, count(*) as total
         from  
             employee_data
         group by 
             EmployeeStatus, EmployeeClassificationType) a
    pivot
        (sum(total)
            for employeeStatus in ([Active], [Future Start], [Leave of Absence], [Terminated for Cause], [Voluntarily Terminated])
        ) as pivotTable
)

SELECT
ISNULL(EmployeeClassificationType,'TOTAL'),
SUM(Active) Active,
SUM(FutureStart)  FutureStart,
SUM(LeaveOfAbsence)   LeaveOfAbsence,
SUM(TerminatedForCause)  TerminatedForCause,
SUM(VoluntarilyTerminated)  VoluntarilyTerminated,
SUM(total) total
FROM 
pivotTable
 group 
    by EmployeeClassificationType with rollup;

dbfiddle

It works, thanks a lot!

@vinita, always happy to help.

with rollup is deprecated, use rollup() instead. You just need to get it over the right columns. Or use grouping sets.

You should use GROUPING SETS instead, as rollup will give intermediate rolling up as well.
Do not use '' to delimit names, only [].
with pivottable as (
-- etc
)
select 
    IIF(GROUPING(EmployeeClassificationType) = 1, 'Grand Total', EmployeeClassificationType) as EmployeeClassificationType,
    sum(Active) as Active,
    sum([Future Start]) as [Future Start],
    sum([Leave of Absence]) as [Leave of Absence],
    sum([Terminated for Cause]) as [Terminated for Cause],
    sum([Voluntarily Terminated]) as [Voluntarily Terminated],
    sum(total) as [Grand Total]
from 
    pivotTable
group by grouping sets
    (EmployeeClassificationType, Active, [Future Start], [Leave of Absence], [Terminated for Cause], [Voluntarily Terminated]),
    ()
);

